# lsort indexing in tcl 8.4 return me bad index

Tags: sorting, indexing, tcl

for example i have

```
lsort -index {1 3} {{a {0 1 2 9 4}} {b {9 8 7 6 5}} {c {0 0 0 0 0}}}
```

i've tried the -index {1 3} in tcl 8.4 that return bad index.
system where I'm running that code is still using TCL 8.4

how do i get the lsort with something like {1 3} to work in tcl 8.4

Comment: You should be aware that 8.4 is no longer in support at all, not even for security issues. (Don't know of any, but wouldn't fix them even if I did know of any.)

Answer (score 2):

`Tcl` 8.4 doesn't support list of indices for `-index` option. If you purely want it for Tcl 8.4, then you can make use of `-command` option.

```
% proc compare {a b} {
    return [string compare [lindex $a 1 3] [lindex $b 1 3]]
}
%
% lsort -command compare {{a {0 1 2 9 4}} {b {9 8 7 6 5}} {c {0 0 0 0 0}}}
{c {0 0 0 0 0}} {b {9 8 7 6 5}} {a {0 1 2 9 4}}
%
```